Let's get critical: Oct 2013 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Chinese Language & Usage Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

What is the difference between 七夕节 and 情人节?
Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)  
Correct pinyin and pronunciation for 太阳
Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)  
V + 到。。。。头上来: Exact meaning and how to use?
Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)  
The mysterious role of 占 in a sentence
Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)  
What does 唰 (shua1) mean?
Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)  
Use of 而 preceding verb
Net Score: 4 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)  
How to improve my Chinese writing
Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)  
Various ways of saying OK?
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)  
How to use 如 to make comparisons or analogies
Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)  
Regional variations of "柴米油盐酱醋茶"
Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)  


There seems to be a good amount of response from native speakers, which is lacking on the forums of most language-learning sites.  This is one thing that sets us apart.
